# Peewee Python Default is not reflecting in DateTimeField

Tags: postgresql, peewee, flask-peewee

Not able to set default timestamp in spite of using DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
The column is set to not null but no default value is set

I have my model

```
import datetime

database = PostgresqlDatabase(dbname,username,password,host)

class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = database

class UserInfo(BaseModel):
     id = PrimaryKeyField()
     username = CharField(unique=True)
     password = CharField()
     email = CharField(null=True)
     created_date = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

when I create table using this model and below code

```
 database.connect()
 database.create_tables([UserInfo])
```

I am getting below table

> ```
>                                   Table "public.userinfo"
> Column        |            Type             |                       Modifiers                       
> --------------+-----------------------------+-------------------------    ------------------------------
>  id           | integer                     | not null default    nextval('userinfo_id_seq'::regclass)
>  username     | character varying(255)      | not null
>  password     | character varying(255)      | not null
>  email        | character varying(255)      | 
>  created_date | timestamp without time zone | not null
> Indexes:
>     "userinfo_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
>     "userinfo_username" UNIQUE, btree (username)
> ```

Here in table created date doesn't set to any default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[When using the default parameter, the values are set by Peewee rather than being a part of the actual table and column definition](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/models.html)

try `created_date = DateTimeField(constraints=[SQL('DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP')])`

Comment: That is crazy.  If you're going to do a "python default", don't quietly override the well established behavioral semantics.  Call it `python_default` or something, and make it crystal clear your ORM **doesn't actually support** real database defaults.